# Eval source code blocks when org-mode files are opened.

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I would like to have src code blocks be eval'd when a `.org` is opened in emacs. It would be even better if I could somehow tag specific src code blocks to identify which blocks to eval on document opening.

Any existing techniques for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in support for this, especially given that it could pose a security risk.
You could add `org-babel-execute-buffer` to your `org-mode-hook`, or if you want to only run some blocks, you could write a custom function which uses `org-babel-map-src-blocks` and add that to the Org-mode hook.